# how to insert values in multiple row based on radio box in mssql db using asp classic and vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am creating one attendance register page using asp classic (attn.asp). in database i have created 3 columns (staffid, attn_status, attn_dt).

where column
**staffid:** store value of staff unique id.
**attn_status:** store value like P(for present) & A(absent) & L(leave).
**attn_dt:** store value of attendance date.

in page i m able to show all employee in row as well as radio button for status by using while / wend.

[image]

my code is as below (page1.asp):

```
<from action="page2.asp">
<td style="text-align:left;"> 
<%= objRs1("Aname") %><%= objRs1("Aid") %><input type="hidden" name="usrid" value="<%= objRs1("Aid") %>"><input type="hidden" name="sattdt" value="<%= adt %>">
</td>
```

in above, retrieved values of employee name, id and date

```
<td style="text-align:center;"> 
<input type="radio" name="<%= objRs1("Aid") %>" id="P" value="P"></input>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;"> 
<input type="radio" name="<%= objRs1("Aid") %>" id="A" value="A"></input>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;"> 
<input type="radio" name="<%= objRs1("Aid") %>" id="L" value="L"></input>
</td>
```

in above form, each record has unique radio group name ( which is id).
i have used while / wend loop but its passing only first record value to next page mean loop not working when i submit above form. that is why its saving only one value to database. please help me where i m wrong and how to do this.

in "page2.asp", i have written code to save above submitted values in multiple row in mssql db:

```
<%
Dim radio, Staffid, attdt
radio = Split(Request.Form("usrid"), ",")(0)
Staffid = Split(Request.Form("usrid"), ",")(0)
attdt = Split(trim(Request.Form("sattdt")), ",")(0)
%>

<%

Dim objRS, objCmd, str
For Each  radio in Request.Form("group1")
Set objCmd  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

str = "insert into Staff_attendance (staff_Aid, staff_attn_dt, staff_attn_status) values(?,?,?)"

With objCmd
.ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
.CommandText = str
.CommandType = adCmdText

.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4g", adInteger, adParamInput, ,Staffid))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg16", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(attdt)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg16q", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(radio)))


.Parameters("@param4g").Value = Staffid
.Parameters("@paramg16").Value = attdt
.Parameters("@paramg16q").Value = radio

end with 
Set objRS = objCmd.Execute()
 Next
%>
```

with above code, in db only one row is adding.

Please help me out to save values id wise in multiple row.

Comment: You are using "radio" in your loop without splitting it into an array.

Comment: @JenR please help me how to split in array

Comment: you did it already, here: Staffid = Split(Request.Form("usrid"), ",")(0)

Comment: @JenR yes i have tried this but value is not saving in db. when i see db, its show empty table

Comment: Didn't it save one row?  That is what your question says?

Comment: @JenR no it didnt save even one row

Comment: Do you need to open the connection first? Or is that implicit?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional I think you are on to something - I don't see a DB connection being declared at all, let alone opening it. lekesh, you should look at that.

Comment: If MM_connDUdirectory_STRING is your db connection, it is not clear here.   If it is your connection string, you need to use it as a parameter to create a DB connection.

Comment: The connection object's [default property is `connectionstring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so I think assigning the connection string to `ActiveConnection` _could_ work. It's just that you might need a subsequent `ActiveConnection.Open`

Comment: @Jen R its saving only one record ftoooooyyyy85 (pls see image above) in db while submitting even i select radio option for other record and one more problem i seen radio button selecting only one at a time from all row (pls see image). if select radio button for absent for ftoooooyyyy85 and than i select again radio button for raghav sachdev91(pls see image) then it remove selection from ftoooooyyyy85. please help me how can i select radio option for each faculty? radio button name i have given "group1" and how can i pass this value for submission?

Comment: You need to give each set of radio buttons a different name - so each row of buttons in your table needs a new name.  Try that first

Comment: @JenR i have used while / wend loop but its passing only first record value to next page mean loop not working when i submit above form. that is why its saving only one value to database. please help me where i m wrong and how to do this. Please have a look to my edited code in above in page1.asp

Comment: Since you are building the page dynamically, go to it  and view the source - then add the HTML that is on the page here.  It is hard to see what's wrong with just the ASP code.